# Homepage redirects to other site of mine?

Tags: database, redirect, wp-redirect

I have a website in which the home page **redirects** to a different site, which is also from me. I tried getting on it yesterday and then, it was fine. But now, this evening, when I never touched a thing, it keeps me redirecting to the other site of mine, which is not what I want of course.

What the hell goes wrong? It has frustrated me, because I was planning to go live today. Can someone help me out please? I checked all the `plugins`, `index.php`, .`js` files and searched all of the files to see if there is a hardcoded link, but without success. Besides, I have checked my `database` and there I could not find a thing to.

PS: only the homepage redirects. Other parts of my website like /contact does not redirect.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing that your Wordpress Address URL or your Site URL (both under Settings> General) are incorrect. You can find them in your database in the options table `option_name` `siteurl`or `home`. You  might have overwritten the original settings while importing your database from a local server or something.

Comment: Nope. I checked that and they are both correct. It was Google Adsense, but I don't know how and why.

Comment: I would suggest contacting them and asking. Sounds annoying.

Comment: Yes, indeed. Going to do that eventually, I guess. Thanks mantis.

Comment: Or you could format the question differently and ask it in StackExchange tagged Adsense. You're probably not the only one ;)

Answer (score 0):

`Google Adsense` was the problem. They redirected me when they could not find an ad to show and that was the URL I stated on the Adsense page. Problem solved.